# How to remove underscore and the characters after it of the elements in a Dictionary

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift5

I have a dictionary that looks like this.

```
    ["price_2": 20.0, "stock_2": 100, "volume_2": "2L", "sku_2": 2, "volume_0": "1L", "sku_0": 1, "price_0": 10.0, "stock_0": 100]
```

I grouped them by its last character. And to remove the underscore and the character after it I use key.droplast(2) but this won't work when there are more characters after the underscore, like when a key becomes volume_150.

```
    Code:
    let dict = Dictionary(grouping: displayValues) { String($0.key.suffix(1)) }.mapValues { 
    $0.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.key.dropLast(2)] = $1.value } }


    Result:
    ["2":["price": 20.0, "stock": 100, "volume": "2L", "sku": 2], 
    "0": ["volume": "1L", "sku": 1, "price": 10.0, "stock": 100]]
```

How do I remove underscore and the characters after it?

Comment: Would `.split(separator: "_")` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **.split(seperator: "_").first** to get the keys like you asked.

```
let yourDictionary =  ["price_2": 20.0, "stock_2": 100, "volume_2": "2L", "sku_2": 2, "volume_0": "1L", "sku_0": 1, "price_0": 10.0, "stock_0": 100] as [String : Any]

for key in yourDictionary.keys {
    let newKey = key.split(separator: "_").first
    print(newKey!)
}
```